# postgresql primary key on delete cascade, syntax error

Tags: postgresql, cascade

I try to create a simple table but there is a syntax error at or near "ON" and I don't know why. Any hint will be helpful.

```
create table Cook(
CookID serial PRIMARY KEY ON DELETE CASCADE,
FirstName varchar(20),
LastName varchar(20),
Background varchar(100)
);
```

Comment: Where in the manual did you find that syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ON DELETE CASCADE must be place on FOREIGN KEY that point to your primary key.